# QT 6 I get a sqeezed layout with different layouts

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt

I am trying to make a layout that roughly looks like this:
[image]

Which I have tried to achieve with multiple different layouts.
However, I end up with something squeezed, that looks like below (this is the result with OVBoxLayout)

[image]

Below is a minimal reproducible example which creates the issue.
What am I missing?

```py
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QTabWidget
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QFormLayout
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QLabel, QPushButton
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt


class CommandWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent: QWidget, save_function, cancel_function) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.save_button = QPushButton('Save')
        self.quit_button = QPushButton('Quit')

        self.save_button.clicked.connect(save_function)
        self.quit_button.clicked.connect(cancel_function)

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.save_button)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.quit_button)


class AboutTab(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent: QWidget) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)

        settings = {
            'Name': 'Test',
            'Version': '1.0.0',
            'Release Type': 'Test'
            }
  
        self.layout = QFormLayout(self)

        self.__add_settings_labels(settings)

    def __add_settings_labels(self, settings: dict[str,str]) -> None:
        for key, value in settings.items():
            key_label = QLabel(f'{key}:')
            key_label.setStyleSheet('font-weight: bold')
            value_label = QLabel(value)

            self.layout.addRow(key_label, value_label)


class SettingsTabDialog(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent: QWidget=None, configurations=None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)

        tab_widget = QTabWidget()
        tab_widget.addTab(AboutTab(self), 'About')

        widget_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        widget_layout.addWidget(tab_widget)

        self.setLayout(widget_layout)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent: QWidget, configuration=None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle('Demo')

        self.settingsTabs = SettingsTabDialog(parent=self, configurations=configuration)
        self.command_buttons = CommandWidget(parent=self, save_function=self.save_configuration, cancel_function=self.quit_app)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.settingsTabs)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.command_buttons, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignRight)
        
    def save_configuration(self):
        print('save')
        
    def quit_app(self):
        print('quit')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    config = None
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    t = MainWindow(None, configuration=config)
    t.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**requirements.txt**

```
pyside6==6.6.0
```

Comment: Use centralwidget: change self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self) to widget = QWidget() self.setCentralWidget(widget) layout = QVBoxLayout(widget) in MainWindow

Comment: Or only change class MainWindow(QMainWindow): to class MainWindow(QWidget):

Comment: Also, always remember to test code in a terminal or prompt, as your code will output a clear warning about this problem: QMainWindow has its own layout, and you cannot set another for it.